# Broken `cron` gh-action workflow

Tags: github

I write as an exercise the GitHub action workflow below.

```
name: Cron CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow every day minutes
  schedule:
    - cron: "01 10 * * 6,7"
    - cron: "01 10 * * 1,2,3,4,5"

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "cron"
  cron:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Run working script

        if: github.event.schedule != '01 10 * * 1,2,3,4,5'
        run: echo "Wake up! Grab a brush and put a little makeup"

      - name: Run resting script
        if: github.event.schedule != '01 10 * * 1,2,3,4,5'
        run: echo "It's not time to make a change! Just relax, take it easy."
```

Although it seems correct to me, I receive the error log `invalid cron attribute "01 10 * * 6,7"`. May you help me understand the error?

[1] https://github.com/trouchet/sappio/actions/runs/3807658008/workflow

Comment: Cron schedules sometimes accept zero-filled integers (`01`), but not all do.

Comment: Great explanation. Do you have any further to offer?

Comment: Linux `cron` allows either 0 or 7 for Sunday, but maybe yours doesn't. Why do you enumerate the weekdays if you want them all, anyway?

Comment: It is just a pun to echo different messages on working and leisure days.

Comment: It's not clear whether your response to my initial comment means that it works if you remove the leading zeroes on integers.

Comment: It did not work, as you can see here: https://github.com/trouchet/sappio/actions/runs/3808333270/workflow

Comment: I made modifications: 1. remove `0` digit; 2. use 0 as Sunday. Now it works. Great!

Comment: Probably post that as an answer and mark it as accepted (once you can).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made following modifications:

1. Remove the initial digit `0`.
2. Use `0` as Sunday instead of `7`.

Now it works!